# SQL Server vector clock

Tags: sql-server, time, vector-clock

Is there a global sequence number in SQL Server which guarantees to increment periodically (even when system time regresses), and can be accessed as part of an insert or update operation?

Comment: For a specific table, `IDENTITY PROPERTY`, otherwise i'd look into `GUID` even though it isn't a sequential increment. Can you explain the use case? Can you define *increments periodically* and explain when **system time** would regress?

Comment: I a pretty sure that the `rowversion` data type will always be globally unique. If you need that property, then you may want to consider it.

Comment: I want to be able to periodically query one or more tables selecting only changed records (I don’t have access to the raw transaction log as this is in SQL Azure). Due to the nature of the data, I can’t entertain the edge case of missing records due to a time adjustment so (I’m assuming) can’t use a DATETIME2 “UtcLastUpdated” column.

Comment: ah, then i'd look into row_versioning or doing it the old school way and not editing records, but inserting new records with an "inserted" time so you can track the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) data type, and the [@@dbts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dbts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function are what you're looking for.

This pattern, of marking rows using a rowversion is implemented at a lower level by the [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) feature.  Which adds tracking of insert/updates and deletes, and doesn't require you to add a column to your table.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure ROWVERSION does what you want.  A ROWVERSION-typed column is guaranteed to be unique within any single database, and, per the SQL documentation, it is nothing more than an incrementing number.  If you just save MAX(ROWVERSION) each time you've finished updated your data, you can find updated or inserted rows in your next update pass by looking fo0r ROWVERSIONs that are bigger than the saved MAX().  Note that you cannot catch deletes in this fashion!

Another approach is to use LineageId's and triggers.  I'm happy to explain that approach if it would help, but I think ROWVERSION is a simpler solution.